# Creating a code128 barcode using FPDF that allows me to manually specify the subsets

Tags: barcode, fpdf, code128

I am using this class to produce a code128 barcode within FPDF. It works well but I have run into a situation where the default A/B/C subset being used by the class isn't being accepted by the people who scan the barcodes.

The barcode string is 28 characters long. They have told me that they're receiving it as `ACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCA` where as it they want the subsets to be 
`BBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC`.

I found this code online and the comments are in French. The language barrier plus the understanding barrier are preventing me from figuring this out.

It did look like `[Bstart]` and `[Cstart]` are relevant but I am unsure where to use this.

In case it helps, my barcode text is `%000121015501999000025136056`

```
class PDF_Code128 extends FPDF {

    protected $T128;                                         // Tableau des codes 128
    protected $ABCset = "";                                  // jeu des caractères éligibles au C128
    protected $Aset = "";                                    // Set A du jeu des caractères éligibles
    protected $Bset = "";                                    // Set B du jeu des caractères éligibles
    protected $Cset = "";                                    // Set C du jeu des caractères éligibles
    protected $SetFrom;                                      // Convertisseur source des jeux vers le tableau
    protected $SetTo;                                        // Convertisseur destination des jeux vers le tableau
    protected $JStart = array("A"=>103, "B"=>104, "C"=>105); // Caractères de sélection de jeu au début du C128
    protected $JSwap = array("A"=>101, "B"=>100, "C"=>99);   // Caractères de changement de jeu

    //____________________________ Extension du constructeur _______________________
    function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4') {

        parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$format);

        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2);           //0 : [ ]               // composition des caractères
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2);           //1 : [!]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1);           //2 : ["]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3);           //3 : [#]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2);           //4 : [$]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2);           //5 : [%]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3);           //6 : [&]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2);           //7 : [']
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2);           //8 : [(]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3);           //9 : [)]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2);           //10 : [*]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2);           //11 : [+]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2);           //12 : [,]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2);           //13 : [-]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1);           //14 : [.]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2);           //15 : [/]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2);           //16 : [0]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1);           //17 : [1]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1);           //18 : [2]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2);           //19 : [3]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1);           //20 : [4]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2);           //21 : [5]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2);           //22 : [6]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1);           //23 : [7]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2);           //24 : [8]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2);           //25 : [9]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1);           //26 : [:]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2);           //27 : [;]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2);           //28 : [<]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1);           //29 : [=]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3);           //30 : [>]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1);           //31 : [?]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1);           //32 : [@]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3);           //33 : [A]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3);           //34 : [B]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1);           //35 : [C]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3);           //36 : [D]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3);           //37 : [E]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1);           //38 : [F]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3);           //39 : [G]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3);           //40 : [H]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1);           //41 : [I]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3);           //42 : [J]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1);           //43 : [K]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1);           //44 : [L]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3);           //45 : [M]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1);           //46 : [N]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1);           //47 : [O]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1);           //48 : [P]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1);           //49 : [Q]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1);           //50 : [R]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3);           //51 : [S]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1);           //52 : [T]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1);           //53 : [U]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3);           //54 : [V]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1);           //55 : [W]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1);           //56 : [X]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3);           //57 : [Y]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1);           //58 : [Z]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1);           //59 : [[]
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1);           //60 : [\]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1);           //61 : []]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1);           //62 : [^]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4);           //63 : [_]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2);           //64 : [`]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4);           //65 : [a]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1);           //66 : [b]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2);           //67 : [c]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1);           //68 : [d]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4);           //69 : [e]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2);           //70 : [f]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4);           //71 : [g]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1);           //72 : [h]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2);           //73 : [i]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1);           //74 : [j]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1);           //75 : [k]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4);           //76 : [l]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1);           //77 : [m]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2);           //78 : [n]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1);           //79 : [o]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2);           //80 : [p]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2);           //81 : [q]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1);           //82 : [r]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2);           //83 : [s]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2);           //84 : [t]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1);           //85 : [u]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2);           //86 : [v]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2);           //87 : [w]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1);           //88 : [x]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1);           //89 : [y]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1);           //90 : [z]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1);           //91 : [{]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3);           //92 : [|]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1);           //93 : [}]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1);           //94 : [~]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3);           //95 : [DEL]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1);           //96 : [FNC3]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3);           //97 : [FNC2]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1);           //98 : [SHIFT]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1);           //99 : [Cswap]
        $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1);           //100 : [Bswap]                
        $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1);           //101 : [Aswap]
        $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1);           //102 : [FNC1]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2);           //103 : [Astart]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4);           //104 : [Bstart]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2);           //105 : [Cstart]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1);           //106 : [STOP]
        $this->T128[] = array(2, 1);                       //107 : [END BAR]

        for ($i = 32; $i <= 95; $i++) {                                            // jeux de caractères
            $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
        }
        $this->Aset = $this->ABCset;
        $this->Bset = $this->ABCset;

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) {
            $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
            $this->Aset .= chr($i);
        }
        for ($i = 96; $i <= 127; $i++) {
            $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
            $this->Bset .= chr($i);
        }
        for ($i = 200; $i <= 210; $i++) {                                           // controle 128
            $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
            $this->Aset .= chr($i);
            $this->Bset .= chr($i);
        }
        $this->Cset="0123456789".chr(206);

        for ($i=0; $i<96; $i++) {                                                   // convertisseurs des jeux A & B
            @$this->SetFrom["A"] .= chr($i);
            @$this->SetFrom["B"] .= chr($i + 32);
            @$this->SetTo["A"] .= chr(($i < 32) ? $i+64 : $i-32);
            @$this->SetTo["B"] .= chr($i);
        }
        for ($i=96; $i<107; $i++) {                                                 // contrôle des jeux A & B
            @$this->SetFrom["A"] .= chr($i + 104);
            @$this->SetFrom["B"] .= chr($i + 104);
            @$this->SetTo["A"] .= chr($i);
            @$this->SetTo["B"] .= chr($i);
        }

    }

    //________________ Fonction encodage et dessin du code 128 _____________________
    function Code128($x, $y, $code, $w, $h) {

        $Aguid = "";                                                                      // Création des guides de choix ABC
        $Bguid = "";
        $Cguid = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($code); $i++) {
            $needle = substr($code,$i,1);
            $Aguid .= ((strpos($this->Aset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O"); 
            $Bguid .= ((strpos($this->Bset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O"); 
            $Cguid .= ((strpos($this->Cset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O");
        }

        $SminiC = "OOOO";
        $IminiC = 4;

        $crypt = "";
        while ($code > "") {
                                                                                        // BOUCLE PRINCIPALE DE CODAGE
            $i = strpos($Cguid,$SminiC);                                                // forçage du jeu C, si possible
            if ($i!==false) {
                $Aguid [$i] = "N";
                $Bguid [$i] = "N";
            }

            if (substr($Cguid,0,$IminiC) == $SminiC) {                                  // jeu C
                $crypt .= chr(($crypt > "") ? $this->JSwap["C"] : $this->JStart["C"]);  // début Cstart, sinon Cswap
                $made = strpos($Cguid,"N");                                             // étendu du set C
                if ($made === false) {
                    $made = strlen($Cguid);
                }
                if (fmod($made,2)==1) {
                    $made--;                                                            // seulement un nombre pair
                }
                for ($i=0; $i < $made; $i += 2) {
                    $crypt .= chr(strval(substr($code,$i,2)));                          // conversion 2 par 2
                }
                $jeu = "C";
            } else {
                $madeA = strpos($Aguid,"N");                                            // étendu du set A
                if ($madeA === false) {
                    $madeA = strlen($Aguid);
                }
                $madeB = strpos($Bguid,"N");                                            // étendu du set B
                if ($madeB === false) {
                    $madeB = strlen($Bguid);
                }
                $made = (($madeA < $madeB) ? $madeB : $madeA );                         // étendu traitée
                $jeu = (($madeA < $madeB) ? "B" : "A" );                                // Jeu en cours

                $crypt .= chr(($crypt > "") ? $this->JSwap[$jeu] : $this->JStart[$jeu]); // début start, sinon swap

                $crypt .= strtr(substr($code, 0,$made), $this->SetFrom[$jeu], $this->SetTo[$jeu]); // conversion selon jeu

            }
            $code = substr($code,$made);                                           // raccourcir légende et guides de la zone traitée
            $Aguid = substr($Aguid,$made);
            $Bguid = substr($Bguid,$made);
            $Cguid = substr($Cguid,$made);

        }   

        $check = ord($crypt[0]);                                                   // calcul de la somme de contrôle
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {
            $check += (ord($crypt[$i]) * $i);
        }
        $check %= 103;

        $crypt .= chr($check) . chr(106) . chr(107);                               // Chaine cryptée complète

        $i = (strlen($crypt) * 11) - 8;                                            // calcul de la largeur du module
        $modul = $w/$i;

        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {                                      // BOUCLE D'IMPRESSION
            $c = $this->T128[ord($crypt[$i])];
            for ($j=0; $j<count($c); $j++) {
                $this->Rect($x,$y,$c[$j]*$modul,$h,"F");
                $x += ($c[$j++]+$c[$j])*$modul;
            }
        }
    }

    function Rotate($angle,$x=-1,$y=-1)
    {
        if($x==-1)
            $x=$this->x;
        if($y==-1)
            $y=$this->y;
        if($this->angle!=0)
            $this->_out('Q');
        $this->angle=$angle;
        if($angle!=0)
        {
            $angle*=M_PI/180;
            $c=cos($angle);
            $s=sin($angle);
            $cx=$x*$this->k;
            $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k;
            $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5F %.5F %.5F %.5F %.2F %.2F cm 1 0 0 1 %.2F %.2F cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps somebody in the future, this is how I solved the issue.

As I know the barcode will always be 28 characters long then I hard coded the creation of `$crypt`

```
$crypt = '';
$crypt .= chr($this->JStart["B"]);
$crypt .= strtr('%0', $this->SetFrom[$jeu], $this->SetTo[$jeu]);
$crypt .= chr($this->JSwap["C"]);       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,2,2) );
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,4,2) );
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,6,2) );
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,8,2) );
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,10,2) );                       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,12,2) );                       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,14,2) );                       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,16,2) );                       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,18,2) );                       
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,20,2) );               
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,22,2) );               
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,24,2) );               
$crypt .= chr( substr($inputCode,26,2) );
```

This then gave me exactly what I needed to create the barcode using the same code as comes as standard with the class:

```
    $check = ord($crypt[0]);                                                   // calcul de la somme de contrôle
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {
        $check += (ord($crypt[$i]) * $i);
    }
    $check %= 103;

    $crypt .= chr($check) . chr(106) . chr(107);                               // Chaine cryptée complète

    $i = (strlen($crypt) * 11) - 8;                                            // calcul de la largeur du module
    $modul = $w/$i;

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {                                      // BOUCLE D'IMPRESSION
        $c = $this->T128[ord($crypt[$i])];
        for ($j=0; $j<count($c); $j++) {
            $this->Rect($x,$y,$c[$j]*$modul,$h,"F");
            $x += ($c[$j++]+$c[$j])*$modul;
        }
    }
```